# Select distinct field from solr as like SQL: select distinct(name) from address

Tags: solr, solrj

I want select all distinct values from Solr.
Right now I am using the query 
http://localhost/solr/MyCore/select?q=type%3AItem&fl=number&wt=xml&indent=true

Using this query I am getting result but duplicate ‘number’ as well. How I can filter these duplicate values.
Like SQL: select distinct(number) from abcd;

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you are asking, but possible ways to do what you need:

- [Faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting)  Add the follwing params: &facet=true&facet.field=number
  Check the rest of many optional params you have to tweak the faceting.
- [Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping)
- [Collalpsing parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my concern is different. Actually I have already getting number as like 
<result name="response" numFound="17157843" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="Number_nk">45454454</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Number_nk">64454</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Number_nk">56566656</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Number_nk">5665656111</str>
</doc>
did you notice the number of found. I am sure that I don't have 17157843 different numbers. some of them are duplicate. How I can avoid the duplicate

Comment: Use Faceting which will give you all unique terms for a field.